# Trading strategy with high probability of small profits and low probability of complete loss

Tags: trading, investment-strategies, terminology

What are some trading strategies that have high probability of small profits and low probability of catastrophic loss? I believe there is an academic term to describe a trading system that shows small consistent profits, but with the risk of a complete loss lurking around the corner. The typical equity curve of such a strategy resembles a straight upward-sloping line (i.e. small but consistent profits), with a cliff at the end that represents a huge loss.

What is the proper term for such a trading system? Could you give some concrete examples (i.e. hypothetical portfolio constructions) that implement such a risky trading system?

Comment: If you were "investing" at a roulette wheel, you would need a Martingale system...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an academic term but it's colloquially called **picking up pennies in front of a steamroller**.

One example is selling far OTM options ([Remember Wall Street’s Viral
Laughingstock, OptionSeller.com?](https://www.institutionalinvestor.com/article/b1lm2xg8g69vbc/Remember-Wall-Street-s-Viral-Laughingstock-OptionSeller-com))

> In economics and finance, a **[Taleb distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taleb_distribution)** is the statistical
> profile of an investment which normally provides a payoff of small
> positive returns, while carrying a small but significant risk of
> catastrophic losses. The term was coined by journalist Martin Wolf and
> economist John Kay to describe investments with a "high probability of
> a modest gain and a low probability of huge losses in any period."

Answer (score 0):

This shape of trade generally gets bucketed into a class of trade called a 'carry' trade, although it can be built in some other ways. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(investment)) for a basic overview of carry, and [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Rise-Carry-Consequences-Volatility-Suppression/dp/1260458407) is also a interesting read if you want to go deeper.